# Run a function every n seconds in python with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an application which already runs infinitely with asyncio event loop run forever and also I need to run a specific function every 10 seconds.

```
def do_something():
   pass

a = asyncio.get_event_loop()
a.run_forever()
```

I would like to call the function do_something every 10 seconds. How to achieve this without replacing asynctio event loop with while loop ?

Edited:
I can achieve this with the below code

```
def do_something():
   pass
while True:
   time.sleep(10)
   do_something()
```

But I dont want to use while loop to run infinitely in my application instead I would like to go with asyncio run_forever(). So how to call the same function every 10 seconds with asyncio ? is there any scheduler like which will not block my ongoing work ?

Comment: its simple just call a function every 10 seconds inside my application. My application is doing other stuffs as well infinitely with run_forever().

Comment: I have edited the question little to get a clear idea.

Comment: not an usual idea, but recursion just do work.

Comment: Recursion reached maximum depth will occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`asyncio` does not ship with a builtin scheduler, but it is easy enough to build your own. Simply combine a `while` loop with `asyncio.sleep` to run code every few seconds.

```py
async def every(__seconds: float, func, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        await asyncio.sleep(__seconds)

a = asyncio.get_event_loop()
a.create_task(every(1, print, "Hello World"))
...
a.run_forever()
```

Note that the design has to be slightly different if `func` is itself a coroutine or a long-running subroutine. In the former case use `await func(...)` and in the latter case use [`asyncio`'s thread capabilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with

```
async def do_something():
   while True:
      await asyncio.wait(10)
      ...rest of code...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(do_something())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: But where will I make a call to the function ?

Comment: @VimalanE check my post, i updated it

Comment: Thanks this also works fine. psowa001