# How to combine multiple async tasks in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

As a newbie I got stuck in here and would appreciate if you could help.

1. Is there a way to shorten / combine the following async tasks?
2. How can I repeat these set of tasks every n seconds forever?

Thank you in advance.

```
def get_tasks1(session1):
    task1 = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        task1.append(asyncio.create_task(session1.get(url1.format(symbol))))
    return task1

async def get_symbols1():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session1:
        task1 = get_tasks1(session1)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*task1)
        for response in responses:
            results1.append(await response.json())

def get_tasks2(session2):
    task2 = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        task2.append(asyncio.create_task(session2.get(url2.format(symbol))))
    return task2

async def get_symbols2():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session2:
        task2 = get_tasks2(session2)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*task2)
        for response in responses:
            results2.append(await response.json())

asyncio.run(get_symbols1())
asyncio.run(get_symbols2())

with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write('%r\n%r\n' % (results1, results2))
```

Comment: Your second question should be covered by [Run a function every n seconds in python with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939800/run-a-function-every-n-seconds-in-python-with-asyncio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you question is practical(you want to solve task rather than learn async deeply) I recommend:

1. Use [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) package, which is based on popular [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking) package to query urls.
2. If in future you want to perform some operations on received data, you probably will want to use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org)
3. To run operation every N seconds:

```
from time import sleep

def operations(): 
    asyncio.run(get_symbols1())
    asyncio.run(get_symbols2())

    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write('%r\n%r\n' % (results1, results2))

while True:
    sleep(60) # 60 seconds
    operations()
```

But it is not safe to put this on scripts itself(possible memory leaking, process could be terminated by OS...), so consider using cron(if periods is more than 1 minute) or any other external tool, that will run your script periodically.